# Laravel 5 elixir config cssoutput not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I am using elixir for some sass compiling, but the 'public' folder is renamed to 'public_html' in this project (convention of our webserver)..

Is it possible to set this public directory globally in my elixir config so I don't have to specifiy it on every elixir function?

```
elixir.config.publicDir = 'public_html';
elixir.config.cssOutput = 'public_html/css';
elixir.config.jsOutput = 'public_html/js';
```

This should work but it does not!

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution, there is a config.js file in de exlixir folder of the node-modules, there you can specify the publicPath directory.

I would love to see other ways to do this though, so any other solutions are welcome!

EDIT: so I was confusing things. I don't need 'cssOutput' but 'publicPath'. If you like to change the default public path you can set the publicPath option using

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.publicPath = 'public_html';
```